# Make JIT compiler to optimize certain classes in debug mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a plugin for a certain game engine(Unity3D). It does run in execution context of the game engine. The game engine runs plugins in debug configuration and the CLR is a customized version of mono (somewhat more complete than .Net 3.5). It's not possible nor desirable for the game engine to run in release mode.

I want JIT compiler to optimize my code even though CLR is running in debug configuration and does not optimize other people's code. Is it possible?

Comment: You could try passing your assemblies to [AOT](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/aot/) and then see if the engine is kind enough to load the precompiled versions. Performance still won't be as good as a dynamic JIT run, but it might be better than under full debugging.

Comment: For .NET Framework, it's as simple as ticking **Optimize code** in the project properties for a Debug configuration, which passes a switch to the compiler (for *your* code). I haven't worked with mono; is there an equivalent switch?

Comment: @Kit I think that switch [just optimizes the intermediate code generated by the compiler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do/); the question is how to enable the JIT compiler to perform optimizations when converting the intermediate code into processor instructions.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. Not knowing mono, I wouldn't be able to answer that, but suggest searching for `mono jit options` and variations as a start unless OP gets an answer.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's a good suggestion. I think I'll try it as a plan B if there aren't any other solutions.